# Validation with SysOperations on D365 X++

Tags: forms, validation, field, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I'm new with x++ and D365, so I often get stuck in very simple tasks. In this case i have created a new field in the extension table EcoResProductParameter called MaxPercentage and put it into the EcoResProductParameter extension form, and I need to check if this value is bigger than the SalesPercentMarkup I select in the InventTable. If so, the percent is updated, else I will receive an error. I tried to do something like this in the DataContract class:

```cs
public boolean validate()
{
    boolean isValid;
    if(salesPercentMarkup <= parameterTable.MaxPercentage)
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isValid = checkFailed('The percentage has exceeded the max');
    }
            
    return isValid;
}
```

but it keeps returning the error because I don't know how to correctly access the value that the user manually insert into the MaxPercentage field, so the problem is in my if statement I suppose. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create [Chain of Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/extensibility/method-wrapping-coc) extension class for the `validateField` method of the `InventTable` table.

This allows you to add custom field validations. In the scenario described in the question, this could look like this:

```cs
[ExtensionOf(tableStr(InventTable))]
final class InventTable_Extension
{
    public boolean validateField(FieldId _fieldIdToCheck)
    {
        // execute the standard validateField logic
        boolean ret = next validateField(_fieldIdToCheck);

        // add custom validation
        if (_fieldIdToCheck == fieldNum(InventTable, SalesPercentMarkup))
        {
            EcoResProductParameters ecoResProductParameters = EcoResProductParameters::find();
            if (this.SalesPercentMarkup > ecoResProductParameters.MaxPercentage)
            {
                // note that the message should be a label and put in double quotes
                ret = checkFailed('The percentage has exceeded the max'); 
            }
        } 

        return ret;
    }
}
```